# Deploying a website builder website

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, website, dedicated-server

I want to create my own custom website builder hosting platform for a niche market. I have plans on hosting 100's plus subdomains off of one primary domain.

Here's my goal:

- Allow register user to create a website, users will be giving a sub
  domain as a url for his/her website(example: `www.Newsite.hosting.com`,
  `wwww.newsite1.hosting.com` etc....
- User's also get to choose from the many custom website templates we have created
- I planed on hosting 100's plus sub-domain at startup.
- User's will also have the ability to update there website via a
  cPanel on the share hosting server.
- I believe the biggest amount of data per sub-domain for 1 site will
  be no greater than 50MB **TOP**

Question:

1. Can a **Baby plan** or **Business plan** shared hosting at HostGator, manage
   this setup at the very beginning, or should I jump right into a Linux
   dedicated server plan?
2. *User cPanel*, *WebSite building tool & template* and *subdomains* all will be hosted on the same domain and share hosting server....is this a good idea?

This is just the basic info for a shared hosting plan

```
              Baby Plan   Hosting plan
Disk Space    UNLIMITED   UNLIMITED
Bandwidth     UNLIMITED   UNLIMITED
Sub Domains   UNLIMITED   UNLIMITED
```

**Linux Dedicated server**

```
Processor:  Intel Xeon 3450 (Quad Core)
DDR Memory: 2 GB RAM
Hard Drive: 2x 250 GB (dual)
Bandwidth:  10 TB
Domains & sub-domain: UNLIMITED
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a dedicated server. You might be able to do this with a VPS like slicehost or linode . A baby or business plan would not work.
2. You would then need to license and install cPanel.

I would consult the cPanel system requirements, http://www.cpanel.net/products/cpanelwhm/system-requirements.html and the cPanel store, https://www2.cpanel.net/store/index.cgi .

Comment: Thanks you SLy, I'll looking into the links you provided.